# strend function in C using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I have created a function for `strend`, which basically returns `1` if string `t` is present at the end of string `s`, however it never returns `1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int strend(char *s, char *t) {
    int  p;
    for (p = 0; p < strlen(s) - strlen(t); p++) {
        *s++;
    }
    printf("%s\n%s\n", s, t);
    if (s == t)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int bool = strend("Hello", "ello");
    printf("%i\n", bool);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me an output of:

```
ello
ello
0
```

So technically I should get `1`. I assume the comparison using pointers is not used in this way?

Comment: You assume right. About every tutorial on strings in C mentions `strcmp` at some time.

Comment: Your code actually tests whether the two strings occupy the same memory location. What you actually want to do is test whether two different memory locations contain the same characters.

Comment: The function doesn't cope with the case of someone passing a longer string for the second argument

Comment: Don't use `bool` as an identifier. This is reserved in C99 and used by `stdbool.h`.

Comment: You're calling strlen at each loop iteration twice.  Another approach is to jump to the end of both strings and compare backwards.  *s++

Comment: another problem not mentioned yet, doing `s++` in the loop affects `strlen(s)` in the loop condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to review your basic knowledge of C strings. There are lots of standard string functions in [`string.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) that can help you with this test.

The basic problem is that the test `s == t` is valid, but you are comparing memory addresses here. You can see that is valid if you change the strings to test to

```
char test[] = "Hello";
int bool = strend_(test, test+1);
```

where `test` obviously is the same as your `"Hello"`, and similarly, `test+1` is the same as `"ello"` (try it by printing them). This *correctly* returns `1` with your routine.

In addition, I get two warnings:

- on `*s++;` "warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]": you increment `s` but also ask what character is at that position through `*s`; and you don't use that information.
  Fix by removing the `*` there.
- on `p < strlen(s) ..`; "warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned long'", because `strlen` does not return a signed integer but an unsigned one (apparently, my header uses `unsigned long`).
  Fix by declaring `p` as `unsigned long`, or even better, `size_t`.

Your entire routine can be condensed to a simple

```
int strend (char *s, char *t)
{
    if (strlen(s) >= strlen(t) && !strcmp (s+strlen(s)-strlen(t),t))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

It's not worth the trouble to cache the result of those four `strlen` calls into 2 temporary variables; a good compiler will work it out and do that for you. (A quick glance to the assembly output of the compiler I'm using – `clang` – shows it does, even with the default optimization settings.)

A slightly modified test, based on @M.M.'s comment:

```
int strend (char *s, char *t)
{
    if (strlen(s) < strlen(t)) return 0;
    return !strcmp (s+strlen(s)-strlen(t),t);
}
```

but attempting to optimize it this way is not as easy parsed as the routine above, and its assembly is ever so slightly "wordy" as well. Personally, I'd go for the more humanly readable version.

Comment: Consider as code has paid the computation cost of the 2 string lengths, suggest `... && !memcmp(s + len_s, t, t_len)) return 1`.

Comment: `if ( condition) return 1; return 0;` could be replaced by `return condition;` since the condition is the result of `&&`

Comment: @chux I'd hope a compiler would perform that optimization

Comment: @M.M: actually, clang also sort of does yours :) `-O3` produces `call strcmp / mov %eax, %ecx / mov 1, %eax / test %ecx, %ecx / je  + 2 / xor %eax,%eax`. The result of `strcmp` may or may not be `1` and so it cannot use its return value right away. If the `strlen` test fails, it jumps straight to that `xor` line. Seems concise enough, and without any human intervention in an attempt to optimize. .. wait, let me add an alternative.

Comment: *It's not worth the trouble to cache the result of those four strlen calls into 2 temporary variables; a good compiler will work it out and do that for you.* I beg to differ! This is a very bad example to show **even** if good compilers might optimise the redundant calls away in this particular example. In most cases, the compiler cannot assume the strings to not change, especially when the pointers are not even declared `const`. If you wish to condense the code, remove the redundant `if`. And if you wish to optimise more, follow chux' advice and use `memcmp`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strcmp(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

```
if (strcmp(s, t) == 0) return 1;
```

This actually compares the contents of the memory pointed to by `s` and `t` rather than their addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is broken in multiple ways:

- The initial loop is a very cumbersome way to advance `p` by the difference of lengths if positive.
- Once you have pointers at the same distance from the end of both strings, You should compare the characters with `strcmp()` (or `memcmp()` if you can first exclude the case of `strlen(s) < strlen(t)`.
- Comparing the pointers obtained after the loop will only work if `t` points inside the string pointed to by `s`, a special case that may or may not be produced by the compiler for the specific call in `main`: `strend("Hello", "ello");`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <string.h>

int strend(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
    size_t len1 = strlen(str1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(str2);
    return len1 >= len2 && !memcmp(str1 + len1 - len2, str2, len2);
}
```

Comment: Solid use of `memcmp` where there is no need to scan a second time for end-of-string. You are a bit more concise and include the *nul-terminating* character, I did `if (slen < tlen) return 0; return !memcmp (s + slen - tlen, t, tlen);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: indeed, there is no need to include the null terminator as the arguments are known to point `len2` from the end.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected/modified your code, here is the code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//#pragma warning(disable:4996)


int strend(char *s, char *t) 
{
   int  p,flag=0,count=0;//count will be the starting index for *t
   p = strlen(s) - strlen(t);//this will be the starting index for *s 
   while(count<strlen(t)) 
   {

       if (*(s+p) == *(t+count))
       {
          flag = 1;
          count++;
          p++;
          continue;
       }
       else
       {
          flag = 0;
          break;
       }
    }

    return flag;
}

int main(void) 
{

   int flag = strend("Hello", "ello");
   printf("%i\n", flag);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a standard way of expressing the pointer arithmetics in `if (*(s+p) == *(t+count))`: `if (s[p] == t[count])`. There is no need for a `continue` inside this simple if/else. There is no need for a `flag` variable, you can insert `return 0;` immediately, and `return 1;` after the loop. (... I didn't check for any further issues. Truth be told, overall it's a reasonably good attempt.)

Comment: This version also doesn't cope with `s` being shorter than `t`.

Comment: `while(count<strlen(t)) ` is very inefficient as you recompute the length of `t` at each iteration of the loop. The compiler might be shrewd enough to optimize this, but you should not rely on it. Compute the length once and store it in a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

This code works too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int strend (char *s1, char *s2);
void main ()
{
    char str1[20] = "somethings";
    char str2[20] = "things";
    int f;
    f = strend (str1,str2);
    if (f==1)
        printf ("1");
    else
        printf ("0");


}
int strend (char *str1, char *str2)
{
    int l = strlen(str1) - strlen(str2);
    str1 = str1 + l;
    int d = strcmp(str1,str2);
    if (d == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior if `str2` is longer than `str1`.

Answer (score 0):

this code works well.

```
int strend(char *s, char *t){
    while(*t & *s){
        if(*t == *s){
            t++;
        }
        s++;
    }
    return *t==*s;
}
```